# Submit selected Multi Selection List box values as new Items

Tags: infopath, form

I have a Sharepoint 2010 list with two columns "Title" and "multi-selection". with a submit button. 
[image: List View]

If I Enter Title and select 'One, Two and Four' then click submit new line Item is created with Selections as "One, Two, Four" as below
[image]

Actually what I needed is 
list each Multi Selection as separate row

Name     | Selection
-------- | --------
TestUser | One
TestUser | Two
TestUser | Four

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SharePoint Designer workflow for this. The idea is to invoke the workflow as below

1. InfoPath save item as `One,Three,Four` - Workflow auto start on the new item
2. Workflow take `One,Three,Four` and update current item with `One` and creates a new item as `Three,Four` - Workflow auto start on the new item
3. Workflow take `Three,Four` and update current item with `Three` and creates a new item as `Four` - Workflow auto start on the new item
4. Inside the workflow check if comma is there. If no comma then do nothing

Comment: Thanks Amal, will you give me more details, I am kind of new to sharepoint.

Comment: @SRon yeah all the hints there in my answer.. you need to do a bit of google.. start with looking for creating sharepoint designer workflow.. then look into string manipulation.. then creating new list item using SPD workflow..

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution using your tip. Its bit complex as i am using share point 2010.   Thanks